# yahoo's API and getQuote from quantmod package for tickers ending "*.MC"

Tags: r, quantmod, yahoo-finance

I'm getting the last bid quote on a bunch of stocks using `quantmod`'s function `getQuote`. I tried with symbols of the form *.MI for instance and get their quotes without any problem. However, when dealing with tickers of the form *.MC get an error although the symbol and information exists as can be seen for instance with [VIS](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=VIS.MC&ql=1) or [EBRO](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=EBRO.MC&ql=1). Does anyone know whether the information contained in the API is different from that shown on the website? does anyone know a way to get over this?

```
library(quantmod)

# note than VIS is a different equity than VIS.MC
getQuote('VIS.MC', what='b2')
getQuote('EBRO.MC', what='b2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Quotes for the spanish exchange might not be available currently for download through the yahoo finance API.

A search for 'MC' in the comments section [here](http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/) yields:

```
ERROSELL
October 7, 2013 at 2:45 am
I have a problem in order to obtain data from exchange .MC (Madrid)

SANDRO GIANGRANDI
October 7, 2013 at 7:03 am
I understand that ALL stock quotes from the spanish exchange are not available.
my feeling is that spanish quotes are available on payment, so Yahoo cannot make them available free of charge.
if you get the historical prices, no problem at all.
I am not sure to have solved your problem, but it is the same problem I faced some time ago.
```

Also, [here](https://yahoo.uservoice.com/forums/170326-finance/suggestions/3463328-impossible-to-download-spanish-market-data):

```
Yahoo Product Support (Admin, Yahoo) responded Dec 21, 2012
Dear Hector,

We regret to inform you that Spanish stocks are no longer available for download.

Our catalog of downloads continues to offer a broad range of stocks to choose from and we hope you will continue to be a consumer of it.

Y! Product Support
```

Hence the error when the 'VIS.MC' symbol exists but not for download:

```
Error in download.file(paste("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=",  : 
cannot open URL 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=VIS.MC&f=d1t1b2'
```